# View too large to fit into drawing cache when calling getDrawingCache()

Tags: android, android-view

I'm trying to take a screenshot of the contents of a LinearLayout.  The layout contains a scrollview that can be of variable height/width.  This code works fine when the layout is not too big (i.e. you don't need to scroll very much off screen to see everything):

```
View v1 = (LinearLayout)theLayout;

v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

However, if the LinearLayout that I'm trying to capture is large, then the application crashes with a null pointer on v1.getDrawingCache().

There is an error in logcat:

> 05-11 13:16:20.999: W/View(17218): View too large to fit into drawing
>   cache, needs 4784400  bytes, only 3932160 available

How can I properly take a screenshot of this layout?  Is there another way to go about it that doesn't use so much memory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791714/take-a-screenshot-of-a-whole-view. check the answer by kameltreiber

Comment: I tried the accepted answer here, but there were some problems with the generated output. The answer here is what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44129753/5987223

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me to capture a large off-screen view in it's entirety:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) 
{
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

It's similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791714/take-a-screenshot-of-a-whole-view), except that I use the view's width/height to create the bitmap

Comment: To make sure it works in all situations you should also call measure() before layout().

Comment: Just to add that this works also for views that are completely invisible (visibility == invisible), which was my case.

Comment: What if I want to change the dimensions of the resulting Bitmap?

Answer (score 1):

As the original question is talking about a ScrollView I just though I would add the following for anyone that was having problems getting the full height. To get the height of the ScrollView, the v.getHeight doesn't work, you need to use:

```
v.getChildAt(0).getHeight()
```

so the full thing would be:

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) result.findViewById(R.id.ScrlView);

loadBitmapFromView(scrollView);

public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) 
{
int height = v.getChildAt(0).getHeight()
int width = v.getWidth()
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
v.draw(c);
return b;
}
```

Just using v.getHeight just gets the screen height, not the full height of the ScrollView.