# capture whole scrollview, bigger than the UI

Tags: android, scrollview, screenshot, capture

I need capture a scrollview that exceed the visible UI, I used this code:

```
ScrollView view2 = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollCapture);
    view2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view2.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bm = view2.getDrawingCache();
```

but it only capture showed screen, not the entire layout.

Is there some method to capture whole layout even isnt showed?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using scrollview use the direct child (only one direct child is allowed). For example if your xml file is

```
<ScrollView
 android:id="@+id/scrollCapture">
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/scrollCaptureChild">
  </LinearyLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

do

```
LinearyLayout view3 = (LinearyLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollCaptureChild);
view3.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view3.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = view3.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but my activity looks like that, anyways seems like there is no way to capture the part of the screen that isnt shown by the UI :(, i tried a lot of things but no way to do that :(

Comment: only the visible part on the screen is captured

Comment: try the solution marked as accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791714/take-a-screenshot-of-a-whole-view

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth(), scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
scrollView.getChildAt(0).draw(c);
```